# Formular consulta de inserccion o actualizacion en SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

En mi aplicacion tengo definida una base de datos en la que voy almacenando numeros del  1 al 99 a medida que van saliendo, si salen mas de una vez se almacenara cuantas veces ha salido cada uno. El problema me viene al formular la consulta, necesito que bien, si el numero no existe este se añada a la base de datos y que en el caso de que exista, se actulice el numero de veces que ha salido. He tratado de hacerlo con esta consulta pero no consigo nada.

Donde -n- es el numero en cuestion que necesito comprobar. tablaBingo es la BD y vecesSalido es la cantidad de veces que un numero ha salido. Cabe decir que los numeros se sumaran de uno en uno siempre en el caso de que se repitan.

```
db.execSQL("IF EXISTS (SELECT " + n + " FROM tablaBingo) INSERT INTO  tablaBingo (numero,vecesSalido) VALUES (" + n + ", "+0+") ELSE UPDATE tablaBingo SET vecesSalido = vecesSalido+1 WHERE numero = " + n + "");
```

Comment: Hola que tal, ve si esta respuesta de la comunidad te sirve https://stackoverflow.com/a/23622827/7621631

Comment: Que se muestra en el LogCat, la estructura de tu Tabla será correcta?